# QWebkit is not able to detect NPAPI plugin

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit

I have developed one NPAPI based plugin and kept in under /usr/bin/mozilla/plugins directory.
I have created one sample html page which merely embeds this npapi plugin. It is getting loaded by mozilaa, but same page when I am trying to load via QWebView , it is not detecting that.

Please help where shall I keep my NPAPI plugin to detect it by Qt.

I am working on Debian Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Answer lies at this link under method name `defaultPluginDirectories`:
https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/4.8/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebCore/plugins/PluginDatabase.cpp